# SQL Group by continuous range of integer values

Tags: sql, sqlite, gaps-and-islands

I have a table like:

```
id  number  owner
47   100      1
48   101      1
49   102      1
50   103      2
51   104      2
52   105      2
53   106      1
54   107      1
55   108      2
56   109      2
57   110      2
```

How to group by continuous range of number and owner to get result like:

```
from_number  to_number    owner
   100          102         1
   103          105         2
   106          107         1
   108          110         2
```

I tried: `SELECT MIN(number), MAX(number), owner FROM table GROUP BY owner`, but got result:

```
MIN(number)  MAX(number)  owner 
   100          107        1
   103          110        2
```

Comment: I'm learning SQL and using SQlite as sandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a type of "groups-and-islands" problem.  You can do this by subtracting a sequence from `number`.  The difference is constant when the `number`s are sequential:

```
select owner, min(number) as from_number, max(number) as to_number
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by owner order by number) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by owner, (number - seqnum);
```

Comment: Thanks! But can you explain, what `(number - seqnum)` means and how it works, please?

Comment: @Googlom . . . That subtracts a sequence from the numbers.  Run the subquery and you will see how this defines the groups you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can try by generating two row number and take their difference

```
select owner, min(number) as min_number, max(number) as max_number
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by owner order by number) as rn1,
             row_number() over(order by number) rn2
      from table_name a
     ) t
group by owner, (rn2 - rn1);
```